# 30 Bitizens Move In Quest Issue

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

In Tiny Death Star I have the mission to have 30 bitizens move in.  I have since made it to 35 total and I still have not received credit for completing this mission.  Is there a secret to finishing this? Or is it some kind of bug?

How do I finish this mission?

Comment: By quest do you mean mission?

Comment: @ZeroStack unless the game has separate quests and missions it's a safe bet that he does.

Comment: @kotekzot I couldnt find anything relating to quests so I was just making sure :)

Comment: Edited for posterity, yah, I did.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Missions do not start with what you currently have.  If you already had 35 bitzens moved in, then it will take an additional 30 to complete this mission.

There would be 2 ways to complete this mission.

## Option 1:

Evict 30 residents and fill those vacancies with new bitzens

### Option 2:

Build 6 more resident floors( 6 floors x 5 spaces = 30) and fill those vacancies with new bitzens

Comment: Do I have to hold onto all 30 new residents? Or could I say have 1 move in then evict them and do that 30 times?

Comment: That I am not sure about.   That would be a great option to test!

Comment: I've evicted 40+ and moved in, and I still can't complete this mission... I don't think your option 1 will work - looks like you have to add in 6 new floors. :(

Comment: Did you do them one by one ? or Evict all of them at once then fill all 30+?

Comment: Both options appear to be correct... I just continued playing evicting and building new floors and once I had 30 new residents... not including any previous ones I had before starting the quest completed.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a bug. I have 55 bitizens now and the quest still has not completed. I'm pretty sure I had 25 or less when the quest started. Lots have moved in and out in that time.

Comment: I'm also having this issue...with this and Darth Vader asking for a floor that isn't coming up, I'm blocked on missions unless I want to spend bucks.  It would be nice if there were a way you could simply table a mission if it's broken or uncompletable.

Comment: I wound up skipping this because of what seemed to be a bug.  But, at least you have this option.  Nor is it critical to the game to finish these missions.